# How to uniquely identify the file name?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Currently we have address flow which errors out mailing file error and physical file error and there's nothing we can do in the job to rename the file.

File Names:

```
s_4800_agency_addresses_1_10_2018_14_13_standard_error.csv - Mailing file
s_4800_agency_addresses_1_10_2018_14_13_1_standard_error.csv - Physical file
```

So here's what my requirement is. I have the above 2 mentioned files. I need the names of these files to be placed in 2 different files. WITHOUT _1 file into one file and WITH _1 file into another file.

Comment: It's very unclear what precisely it is you are trying to do.  Which of those are you trying to "identify"?

Comment: Hello DopeGhoti,  I am trying to identify both the files since I need to give both files as input to different flows again to process. The pbm is the about the date and time generated between the filename.

Comment: Hi! If you can present your problem as a sample input and expected output, there is a chance someone here can understand what you want and help.

Comment: Hello, So here's what my requirement is. I have the above 2 mentioned files. I need the names of these files to be placed in 2 different files. WITHOUT _1 file into one file and WITH _1 file into another file.

Comment: @user276024: Please update the *text* of your question accordingly, to reflect what you now say in your comment is your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This question has changed a lot from the original. At this point, it seems that your requirement is to collect pairs of file names for insertion into two output files.

For this you will want to use your shell's *file globbing* feature. A file glob solution for your case isn't difficult if you enable the `extglob` shell option, and if your file format for the minute element of your timestamp is always two digits. In that case, try:

```
for physical in *_addresses_+([0-9_])_1_standard_error.csv ; do
  mailing=${physical/_1_s/_s}
  # Do your own thing, but for testing ...
  printf "Pair:\n  %s\n  %s\n" "$mailing" "$physical"
  done
```

Now, for the next part of your requirement, you seem to want to place the names of each pair of files into some third and fourth output files. For that you can use either `printf` if you just want a simple output list, or `sed` for more complicated insertions.

For the first (simple) case:

```
for physical in *_addresses_+([0-9_])_1_standard_error.csv ; do
  mailing=${physical/_1_s/_s}
  printf "%s\n" "$mailing"  >> path/to/your_mailing_list.txt
  printf "%s\n" "$physical" >> path/to/your_physical_list.txt
  done
```

For the second, more complex case, prepare each output template file with two guaranteed unique strings, one for `$physical` and one for `$mailing`, and then use `sed` to replace those strings with the filenames. In the following, my chosen unique strings are `@physical` and `@mailing`, the template files are called `physical_template.txt` and `mailing_template.txt`, and the final outputs will be uniquely name files of the form `result_{$physical or $mailing}.txt:`

```
for physical in *_addresses_+([0-9_])_1_standard_error.csv ; do
  mailing=${physical/_1_s/_s}
  sed "s/@physical/$physical/g" physical_template.txt > result_$physical.txt
  sed "s/@mailing/$mailing/g" mailing_template.txt > result_$mailing.txt
  done
```

Answer (score 2):

You may iterate over a pattern that matches the first type of file and pick out the second type of file by modifying each of those names:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -f mailfiles.txt
rm -f physicalfiles.txt

for mailfile in s_4800_agency_addresses_*_standard_error.csv; do
    prefix=${mailfile%_standard_error.csv}
    physicalfile="${prefix}_1_standard_error.csv"

    if [ -f "$physicalfile" ]; then
         printf '%s\n' "$mailfile"     >>mailfiles.txt
         printf '%s\n' "$physicalfile" >>physicalfiles.txt
    fi
done
```

In each iteration of the above loop, `$mailfile` will be a filename from the current directory that matches the pattern `s_4800_agency_addresses_*_standard_error.csv`, for example any of the two filenames that you mention.

From this, we pick out the prefix, which is everything but the ending `_standard_error.csv`, and we construct a new filename by adding `_1_standard_error.csv` to that prefix.  If that resulting name corresponds to an existing file, then we know that `$mailfile` is what you call a "mail file" and that `$physicalfile` is the corresponding "physical file", and we print the two names into `mailfiles.txt` and `physicalfiles.txt` respectively (these result files are initially deleted).

If there is no file corresponding to the newly constructed filename, then we've hit one of the "physical files" (or a "mail file" without a corresponding "physical file") and it is ignored.

Running this:

```
$ ls -1
s_4800_agency_addresses_1_10_2018_14_13_1_standard_error.csv
s_4800_agency_addresses_1_10_2018_14_13_standard_error.csv
```

(script is run here)

```
$ ls -1
mailfiles.txt
physicalfiles.txt
s_4800_agency_addresses_1_10_2018_14_13_1_standard_error.csv
s_4800_agency_addresses_1_10_2018_14_13_standard_error.csv

$ cat mailfiles.txt
s_4800_agency_addresses_1_10_2018_14_13_standard_error.csv

$ cat physicalfiles.txt
s_4800_agency_addresses_1_10_2018_14_13_1_standard_error.csv
```

(blank lines added for readability)